# delphi in vista

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, permissions, bde

i have one problem
when i run my program in delphi7
have one error message

> "unknown table type - permission denied - file:c:\PDOXURS.NET   direcory C:\"

i dont know of make
tk for one answer

Answer (score 11):

On Vista, normal users do not have write-access to c:\, so you get the Permission Denied error message when trying to use Paradox since it needs to write to some files.

Two Good Options:

- Change the Net Dir in the BDE Admin to a path the user has access to

  - BDE Admin
  - Configuration
  - Drivers => Native Paradox
  - Change Net Dir
  - Apply
- Adjust the access rights on the required files on c:\ to allow the user access

and one bad option:

- Run the program as Administrator

Comment: normal users don't have access to WRITE to c:\, they can read fine.  Paradox needs to open that file for read/write access.

Comment: Thanks skamradt, you're right of course. I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to be aware of is the virtual store.  It may contain a copy of your BDE configuration, which you will probably want to delete.  I'm currently not in front of a vista machine but the path is something like \users\username\appdata\local\virtual store  (or something similar).  There will then be a subdirectory for program files\common files\borland shared\bde - you will want to delete the files in here.